# What is the best way to transfer oozie workflows from one user to another?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I am trying to move oozie workflows belonging to a former team member to a general account so we can understand how they had set up configurations when trying to implement new workflows.

I've tried following the documentation in [this Hue 'guide'](http://gethue.com/how-to-manage-the-hue-database-with-the-shell/#comment-78843), but I'm not sure what the purpose of copying the database is, and I'm unclear on where I would run the following python script, which they provided, to perform the transfer.

```
from desktop.models import Document2
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

u1 = User.objects.get(username='bob')
u2 = User.objects.get(username='joe')

Document2.objects.filter(owner=u1, type='oozie-workflow2')
> [<Document2: MyWf - bob>]

Document2.objects.filter(owner=u1, type='oozie-workflow2').update(owner=u2)
> 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [Hue shell](http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/administrator/administration/user-management/#reset-a-password) via:

```
build/env/bin/hue shell
```

from the Hue project root directory.